# Horizontal UIScrollView swipe left and right doesn't work after long gesture?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a scrollview. It behaves as a slider.(Left to right, Right to left). If I swipe left or swipe right, it works. No problem. But If firstly I make long press and then I try to swipe left or right, it doesn't work.

```
  - (void)initCarouselScroll
    {
        [self.carouselScroll removeFromSuperview];
        self.carouselScroll = nil;
        self.carouselScrollHeight = self.view.frame.size.height;
        self.carouselScrollWidth = self.view.frame.size.width;
        self.carouselScroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.carouselScrollWidth, self.carouselScrollHeight)];
        self.carouselScroll.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.carouselScroll.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
        self.carouselScroll.tag = 500;
        self.carouselScroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
        self.carouselScroll.directionalLockEnabled = YES;
        self.carouselScroll.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
        self.carouselScroll.pagingEnabled = YES;
        self.carouselScroll.delegate = self;
        self.carouselScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.carouselScrollWidth * [self.bannerList count], self.carouselScrollHeight);
        [self.carouselScroll setContentOffset:CGPointZero];

        [self.view addSubview:self.carouselScroll];
        [self.view sendSubviewToBack:self.carouselScroll];

        NSUInteger maxLoad = 3;
        if ([self.bannerList count] < maxLoad) {
            maxLoad = [self.bannerList count];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < maxLoad; i++) {
            [self loadImageFor:i];
        }
        [self updateSelectedDotImage:0];
    }

- (void)loadImageFor:(int)index
{
    if (index < 0 || index >= [self.bannerList count]) {
        return;
    }
    AnyImageView* imageView = (AnyImageView*)[self.carouselScroll viewWithTag:index];
    if (!imageView) {

        Banner* banner = [self.bannerList objectAtIndex:(index)];
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(self.carouselScrollWidth * (index), 0, self.carouselScrollWidth, self.carouselScrollHeight);

        NSString* imageUrl = banner.iphoneImage;
        if (self.deviceType == DeviceTypeIpad) {
            imageUrl = banner.ipadImage;
        }
        AnyImageView* imageView = [[AnyImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame picPath:imageUrl isWhite:NO];
        imageView.tag = index;

        UITapGestureRecognizer* singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(bannerButtonClicked:)];
        UILongPressGestureRecognizer* longTap = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPressGestures:)];

        UIButton* button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [button addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
        [button removeGestureRecognizer:longTap];
        button.frame = frame;
        button.tag = index;
        button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        [self.carouselScroll addSubview:imageView];
        [self.carouselScroll addSubview:button];
    }
}
```

Comment: That is because you are adding button on scrollview with same height and width. Scrollview interface is overridden by button

Comment: Thank you. It worked. :)